How customize SpringDoc OpenApi definition from Spring Cloud Gateway service
I want add security schema to every OpenApi's of my services.
I try
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apis(OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer) {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("notifications").pathsToMatch("/v3/api-docs/notifications").addOpenApiCustomizer(openApiCustomizer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer() {
        Info apiInfo = new Info()
                .title(OpenApiDesc.API_TITLE)
                .version(OpenApiDesc.API_VERSION)
                .contact(new Contact())
                .description(OpenApiDesc.API_DESCRIPTION)
                .termsOfService(OpenApiDesc.API_TERMS_OF_SERVICE)
                .license(new License());
        return openApi -> openApi.info(apiInfo).components(new Components()
                    .addSecuritySchemes("bearer-key",
                            new SecurityScheme()
                                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                    .scheme("bearer")
                                    .bearerFormat("JWT")));
    }
}

actual:

expected:


Use below config this will help you get the expected result
@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(name = "bearer-key", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP)
public class OpenApiConfig {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apis(OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer) {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("notifications").pathsToMatch("/v3/api-docs/notifications").addOpenApiCustomizer(openApiCustomizer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openApiCustomizer() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                .title(OpenApiDesc.API_TITLE)
                .version(OpenApiDesc.API_VERSION)
                .contact(new Contact())
                .description(OpenApiDesc.API_DESCRIPTION)
                .termsOfService(OpenApiDesc.API_TERMS_OF_SERVICE)
                .license(new License()))
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("bearer-key"));
    }
}

Note: You can pass other security information as part of this @SecurityScheme
Expected result

Bean openApiCustomizer must return OpenApiCustomizer for bean apis. I try this config with SecutityScheme annotation and it doesn't work.  I want remind than this config inside my gateway service and group "notifications" is other service which api-docs I get with http.

I have remove @SecuritySchema and it's still returning correct response. Have you add any swagger config as part of application.yml file. If yes, include in your question.
